# Specified cast is not valid - exception

Tags: c#, oracle

I have following situation. I have PL/SQL - where I clicked "Describe" button on table and it told me type of one column is "INTEGER".
On the C# side I have this code to read that value:

```
    // GET ID
   if (!rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("ID")))
   {
      int ID =  rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("ID")); // Here I get exception
   }
```

But I get this exception:

> Specified cast is not valid.

Can anyone help?

Stack trace:

> StackTrace    "   at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)\r\n   at
>   GatewayFileImporter.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\g\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\FileImpo\FileImpo\Form1.cs:line 86" string

Comment: On where do you get this exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül: I updated code- I think when I do GetInt32

Comment: I don't see something wrong here. Are you sure that this snippet raises the exception?

Comment: Does you column have null value? Also, I couldnt understand the usgae of `if (!rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("ID")))`.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: GetOrdinal returns column ID - then I pass this column ID to IsDbNull to check if it is NULL or not, is it clear now? (When I know it is not NULL I read it then)

Comment: @User30044: Yes, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd.aspx)

> This data type is an alias for the `NUMBER(38)` data type, and is
>   designed so that the `OracleDataReader` returns a `System.Decimal` or
>   OracleNumber instead of an integer value. Using the .NET Framework
>   data type can cause an overflow.

Looks like this mapped to decimal in .NET side and you need to use [`GetDecimal` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getdecimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead;

```
decimal ID =  rdr.GetDecimal(rdr.GetOrdinal("ID"));
```

Comment: So basically you say INTEGER (on the PL/SQL side) --> corresponds to Decimal on .NET?

Comment: @User30044 It seems yes.

Comment: Hmm okk.. about style that I am using rdr.GetOrdinal("ID") twice, seems ok to you?

Comment: @User30044 Yeap, that's ok.

Comment: And the style in general also the NULL check, seems OK to you? Thanks. I think the exception is at least gone now ...

Comment: What is meant here "Using the .NET Framework data type can cause an overflow." ? (from your answer)